# Session state ASP.NET Core add collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I need a cache for saving a collection of data specific to the user. For example filter results, which will be collection of data.

Is there any way to do it by ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to do this. Take a look at [the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2).